# 'Too many body parameters' Exception on Feign Client

Tags: java, spring, rest, netflix-feign

I am using Springs Feign Client functionality to communicate from one micro service to another.

Now, the called service exposes a REST interface which accepts a file and a related (JSON)Object.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {CONVERT_PATH, APPLICATION_PATH + CONVERT_PATH}, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = CONTENT_TYPE)
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> convert(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("input") Input in) {...}
```

This interface is functioning fine, I have verified this by sending a valid multipart/mixed entity to it from a different source.

Then, in my other service, I have setup a matching feign client to use this interface:

```
@FeignClient("convert")
public interface ConvertClient {
    @RequestMapping(value = CONVERT_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/mixed")
    ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> convert(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("input") Input in);
}
```

Again, the connection from one service to the other is working, Ive verified this with a different request interface in the feign client (one which does not use multiple parts).

When I try to build the (client)service with this particular interface-method I get the following exception:

```
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: 
public abstract org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity <..>.feign.ConvertClient.convert(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,<..>.Input)
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work? 
Its possible to reach the REST interface as i stated, and different feign calls are working. If I am not mistaken this should work. 
Is Springs Feign just not supporting multipart/mixed for feign interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

I just published a custom Feign Encoder that is able to encode multipart requests (one or more files, alongwith json parts). You can try it [here](https://github.com/pcan/feign-client-test). Let me know if there are other use cases that can be implemented, feel free to open issues.