# Can I generate a Spring Feign client with Multipart parameters?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I am getting the error:
   "Method has too many Body parameters"
when trying to generate a Spring Feign client

```
@RequestMapping(value="/media", method=RequestMethod.POST)
String uploadMedia(@RequestHeader("Authentication") String token,
    @RequestPart("media") MultipartFile audio, 
    @RequestPart("a-json-object") SomeClass someClazz,
    @RequestPart("another-json-object") AnotherClass anotherClazz);
```

I found the following solution, which works when using regular Feign annotations, but not with Spring MVC annotations:

['Too many body parameters' Exception on Feign Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085157/too-many-body-parameters-exception-on-feign-client)

Comment: Not right now, no.

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible now. Add the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign.form</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-form</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign.form</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-form-spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
...
```

and use this client configuration:

```
@FeignClient(name = "file-upload-service", configuration = FileUploadServiceClient.MultipartSupportConfig.class)
public interface FileUploadServiceClient extends IFileUploadServiceClient {

    @Configuration
    public class MultipartSupportConfig {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @Scope("prototype")
        public Encoder feignFormEncoder() {
            return new SpringFormEncoder();
        }
    }
}
```

Example was taken from: [feign-form docs](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-form#spring-multipartfile-and-spring-cloud-netflix-feignclient-support)