# How do I configure a HystrixFeign client?

Tags: hystrix, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I have a Spring Boot app, but I cannot take advantage of @EnableFeignClient because multipart is not supported. (See [Can I generate a Spring Feign client with Multipart parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121424/can-i-generate-a-spring-feign-client-with-multipart-parameters)).

I am creating my own HystrixFeign client using the builder:

```
Request.Options options = new Options(connectTimeout, readTimeout);
MyClient client = HystrixFeign.builder()
             .client( new OkHttpClient() )
             .encoder(new FeignSpringFormEncoder())
             .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
             .logger(new Slf4jLogger())
             .logLevel(Logger.Level.HEADERS)
             .options(options)
             .target(MyClient.class, vbApiUrl, fallback);
```

How can I configure other properties of Hystrix? I want to set the execution isolation strategy, the circuit breaker sleep window, volume threshold, error threshold percentage?

Is it enough to include them in my application.properties file? How can I verify that these properties are applied to the "uploadMedia" endpoint ?

```
hystrix.command.uploadMedia.execution.isolation.strategy=THREAD  hystrix.command.uploadMedia.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=10000
hystrix.command.uploadMedia.execution.timeout.enabled=false
hystrix.command.uploadMedia.execution.isolation.thread.interruptOnTimeout=false
hystrix.command.uploadMedia.fallback.enabled=true
hystrix.command.uploadMedia.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds=5000
hystrix.command.uploadMedia.circuitBreaker.requestVolumeThreshold=20
hystrix.command.uploadMedia.circuitBreaker.errorThresholdPercentage=50
```

Comment: Never mind. I enabled @EnabledFeignClients anyway and the configuration properties in application.properties are being applied. I confirmed this by enabling the logger on com.netflix.hystrix